# JavaScript Slide Error

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, slider

I am trying to do a slider which changes with a button click.Here is my JS code.

```
    var img1=document.getElementById("p1");
    var img2=document.getElementById("p2");
    var img3=document.getElementById("p3"); 

    function slidee(){
    var sl=0;
        if(sl==0){
            img1.style.display= "none";
            img2.style.display= "block";
            sl=1;
        }
        if(sl==1){
            img2.style.display= "none";
            img3.style.display= "block";
            sl=2;
        }
        if(sl==2){
            img3.style.display= "none";
            img1.style.display= "block";
            sl=0;
        }
    }

var btnn=document.getElementById("btn");
btnn.onclick=slidee;
```

and this is my CSS codes for 3 images

```
#p1{
    display:block;
}
#p2{
    display:none;
}
#p3{
    display:none
```

Nothing changes when I make p1 block and others none.However,when I make p2 or p3 block and others none,slider goes to p1 and then doesnt change again.What is the problem here?
And this is the html of div

```
<div id="second">
<img class="mySlides" id="p1" src="rbt.jpg">
<img class="mySlides" id="p2" src="scv.jpg">
<img class="mySlides" id="p3" src="hml.jpg">
<button id="btn">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: post your html too

Comment: I edited and added html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the variable outside of the function and use `else if`.

```
var sl=0;
function slidee(){
    if(sl==0){
        img1.style.display= "none";
        img2.style.display= "block";
        sl=1;
    } else if(sl==1){
        img2.style.display= "none";
        img3.style.display= "block";
        sl=2;
    } else if(sl==2){
        img3.style.display= "none";
        img1.style.display= "block";
        sl=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got u but when I take it out of function it is still same.

Comment: You also have to use `else if`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing changes when I make p1 block and others none.However,when I make p2 or p3 block and others none,slider goes to p1 and then doesnt change again.

What should change? 
each time you call you method, what will happen at first???

```
    function slidee(){
      var sl=0;

      if(sl==0){
        img1.style.display= "none";
        img2.style.display= "block";
        sl=1;
      }
      ...
    }
```

> What is the problem here?

each time `sl` is set to  `0` on every function call.

```
    var sl=0
```

Comment: When I click on button,p1 should be none and p2 should be block then when I click button again p2 should be none and p3 should be block.